# Instances launch type difference in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the use of dedicated instance in real life where it is mentioned in AWS that no other user will share your hardware. How it is different from Reserved instances? How things will be different if nobody is using my hardware and when people are using but i am not getting to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved instances are a billing construct. You commit to pay for an EC2 instance for a minimum period of time (1 year or 3 years) in return for a discount (up to 72%).

Dedicated instances are a physical placement construct. No other customer's VMs will run on the same physical hardware as yours. This is typically useful for customers with stringent compliance requirements.

Comment: That's what my question is. Why would i use dedicated instances? Where are those stringent compliance used? And how I can be sure that if I am using dedicated instances then what is actually happening at backend?

In my span of developer's life uptil now, I haven't faced any requirement as such. Have you faced any? Please share

Comment: AWS builds things that customers asked them to build. Typically the underlying requirement is either regulatory or licensing. Use it if you want, or need, more isolation than a hypervisor can provide. One example is the US Department of Defense IL5, which requires physical isolation (dedicated infrastructure), for example.

Answer (score 0):

People would generally use dedicated infrastructure in AWS if they have reasons to not use multi-tenant infrastructure such as for compliance (certain industries such as financial must not share any infrastructure with others).

Reserved instances primarily exist as a discounted price you can pay for a specific instance type. Additionally you can have a capacity reservation for a specific availability zone guaranteeing availability in that AZ. This reserved instance could be on a shared-tenancy piece of hardware with other users. You can also reserve dedicated for a cheaper price.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/

Comment: I would like to know what type of industries have such demand/compliances? Can you please share?

Comment: Primarily banking, government, healthcare, telecommunications. There will be many businesses based on regulatory factors such as annual income, payment capture and information that is being used/stored.